# Is it possible to Control a flood in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on an **Android** app that uses firebase **realtime-database** to store messages from users for a public chat. Since I am pretty new to firebase security, I was wondering whether it is possible to control a flood of messages to the public chat.

I have implemented the firebase rules as such that,a user needs to be authenticated before sending a message to the public chat.

However I am curious to know whether it is possible to flood the public chat if a user happen to authenticate using firebase **javascript** or **nodejs** library and write a loop to send messages continuously. Hence using up the **bandwidth** set for my firebase app.

*Below is an example of my Firebase database design for the public chat node*

```
"exmaplePublicChatName":{
  "message1":{
    "timestamp": 324324324,
    "uid": "uid",
    "message": "message1"
  },
  "message2":{
    "timestamp": 324324234,
    "uid": "uid",
    "message": "message2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can do this on the client part. Before sending data capture the last time. When sending another request in a time frame like `2seconds`  dont allow the code to send a push to `firebase`. It will depend on how you set the rules before sending it to firebase.

Comment: So if the last request was just `2 seconds ago` print an **error** containing `You have send to many request please wait or something`

Comment: Guys please read the question carefully. The app is developed for Android but what I have asked is whether I could do anything to control a flood that someone is sending through firebase javascript or node.js library, since anyone can get the firebase credentials from the APK file by decompiling it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `".write": "!data.exists()" for testing if the same data is repeated also ".validate": "newData.child('timestamp').val() <= root.child('exmaplePublicChatName').child(messageId).child('timestamp').val() - 2000"` to test the difference between the two messages is 2 seconds or not no one can hack, broke or guess the random id generation of firebase

Comment: What is `messageId`?

Comment: @RohitNavarathna For example purpose, he has used messageId to explain an auto generated id thats generated when firebase uses the push function. Basically its the unique ID for the message.

Comment: Yeah but which `messageId` will Firebase check while validating the timestamp?

Comment: you have to send the last messageId with the request and change it with the id like this `.child(newData.child(lastId))`

Comment: @OussemaAroura This is definitely a solution.. just not a foolproof one.. a malicious user could potentially guess a messageId of a previous message and spam with that.

Comment: he couldn't firebase generate the ID so no one can broke or guess or hack the random algo

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your answer

Comment: done, if this is what you are looking for please check it as answered :)